# How to target mui elements and classes with styled components?

Tags: material-ui, styled-components

I am struggling big time migrating from makeStyles from material ui to styled components. I have never used material ui and I am very beginner with styled-components. I have been checking documentation from both and I am confused and not finding what I really need. The documentation I find is usually about @mui which I understand is the newest version of Material UI. Then they would use import { styled } from "@mui/system"; and some other options...

What I want is to remove makeStyles and use styled-components with material ui.

I have this styling:

```
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/styles';

import {
    Table,
    TableHead,
    TableRow,
    TableCell,
    TableBody,
    TableFooter,
    Toolbar,
    FormControlLabel,
    Checkbox,
} from '@material-ui/core';

    const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: any) => ({
        tableOverflowWrapper: {
            maxWidth: '100%',
            overflowX: 'auto',
            border: 'black',
            backgroundColor: 'blue',
        },
        headerRow: {
            '& > th': {
                whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
            },
        },
        footerRow: {
            lineHeight: '54px',
            '& td': {
                fontSize: '0.9em',
                fontWeight: 500,
                textTransform: 'uppercase',
                color: `${theme.palette.grey[750]}`,
                backgroundColor: theme.palette.pacific[100],
                whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
            },
        },
        toolbar: {
            justifyContent: 'space-between',
        },
    }));
```

Implemented in this table

```
            <Table>
                <TableHead>
                    <TableRow className={classes.headerRow}>
                        <TableCell />
                        <TableCell />
                        {data?.months?.map(m => (
                            <TableCell key={m} align="right">
                                {m}
                            </TableCell>
                        ))}
                    </TableRow>
                </TableHead>
                <TableBody>
                    {data?.values?.map((intervalRow, i) => (
                        <React.Fragment key={intervalRow?.interval}>
                            <CollapsableRow
                                row={intervalRow}
                                isExpandedInitially={Boolean(i > 0)}
                                isShowingTrends={isShowingTrends}
                            />
                        </React.Fragment>
                    ))}
                </TableBody>
                <TableFooter>
                    <TableRow className={classes.footerRow}>
                        <TableCell />
                        <TableCell>Total Book Value Non-Performing</TableCell>
                        {data?.totalBookValueNonPerforming?.map((val, i) => (
                            <TableCell align="right" key={i}>
                                {val}
                            </TableCell>
                        ))}
                    </TableRow>
```

This is what I have done so far but I am stuck, I am not really targeting th in HeaderRow, td from FooterRow and it seems my theme props is not working either. How can I do this right?

```
const TableOverFlowWrapper = styled.div`
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
`;

const HeaderRow = styled(TableRow)`
    & > th:
    white-space: nowrap;
`;

const FooterRow = styled(TableRow)(
    ({ theme }) => `
    line-height: 54px;
    & > th:
    font-size: 0.9em;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: ${theme.palette.grey[750]};
    background-color: ${ theme.palette.pacific[100]};
    white-space: nowrap;
`,
);
```